# Regex keep only lines with ".de"

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, line

I have a document with domains for example

```
http://www.example.me/?p=1 
http:/example.de/index.php 
http://www.example.com/index.php/hello-world/
```

there are different endings (.me .com .de .... ) now I only want to keep the lines with the .de ending

thank you

Comment: You haven't tried anything? Seems you just came here for a copy-paste answer instead of researching for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern `^(?!.*\.de).*$` and use regex to modify ONLY the lines that don't contains **.de** in the URL

Note that you will need NotePad++ with a version 6 or newer..
see the demo below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex for domain searching:

`^https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.de\/`

Comment: I suspect the domains won't all contain the word `"example"`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` helps you perform a regular expression match. You can `keep lines with .de` like this:

```html
<?php
if (preg_match("#\.de#", "www.example.de")){
//Keep line
}
>
```